# Unable To Work Out Where To Incorporate The Await In Async Function

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch-api

I have a set of forms relating to images (each form is used to add details to a respective image fetched from a MySQL database). The backend is handled with PHP, but the details from these images are sent to the database using the javascript Fetch API.

What I want do is show a button to 'upload more images' when the current list of forms has been submitted and the relevant data added to the database (i.e. no more images to process).

I'm using a `for of` loop so I can use async/await, but I can't get it to play ball.

In the code below I've made the `processImageFormats()` function `async` but I can't work out how to make the if statement after `item.remove()` "await" until the fetch() has happened? And is that the correct sequence of events that needs to happen?

Each time an image form is processed/submitted to the database the `item.remove()` removes that form element from the document.

I tried looking at this question [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop) amongst others and thus changed it to a `for of` loop from a forEach loop, but can't work out how to incorporate the `await` part to solve the problem at hand.

**JavaScript**

```
var imageForms = document.querySelectorAll('.image-upload-details-form');

var uploadMoreImages = document.querySelector('#upload-images-link');

async function processImageForms() {

    for (let item of imageForms) {
        
        item.addEventListener("submit", function (evt) {
        
            evt.preventDefault();

            const formData = new FormData(this);

            fetch("upload-details.php", {
                method: 'post',
                body: formData
            }).then(function(response){
                return response.text();
            }).then(function(text){
                console.log(text);
            }).catch(function (error){
                console.error(error);
            })

            item.remove();

            // ** show or hide 'upload more images' link when there are no more forms to process - the bit that isn't working **
            if (item.length === 0) {
                uploadMoreImages.style.display = 'inline-block';
            }

        })

    }
    
}

processImageForms();


// show or hide 'upload more images' link on pageload
if (imageForms.length === 0) {
    uploadMoreImages.style.display = 'inline-block';
} else {
    uploadMoreImages.style.display = 'none';
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a id="upload-images-link" href="upload.php">UPLOAD MORE IMAGES</a>
```

Comment: Did you try `let response = await fetch("upload-details.php", { method: 'post', body: formData});` ?

Answer (score 2):

In this case it's not so much a question of using a `for` loop to be able to `await`, because regardless of the loop structure you're still inside of a callback function:

```
item.addEventListener("submit", function (evt) {
```

To `await` anything in the function it first needs to be `async`:

```
item.addEventListener("submit", async function (evt) {
```

This whole chain resolves to a `Promise`:

```
fetch("upload-details.php", {
    method: 'post',
    body: formData
}).then(function(response){
    return response.text();
}).then(function(text){
    console.log(text);
}).catch(function (error){
    console.error(error);
});
```

You can `await` the whole thing:

```
await fetch("upload-details.php", {
    method: 'post',
    body: formData
}).then(function(response){
    return response.text();
}).then(function(text){
    console.log(text);
}).catch(function (error){
    console.error(error);
});
```

Though I imagine it's cleaner and more consistent to `await` each step.  Including the `catch`, the whole thing might look like this:

```
try {
    let response = await fetch("upload-details.php", {
        method: 'post',
        body: formData
    });
    let text = await response.text();
    console.log(text);
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

Comment: Hi @David. It still isn't workinng but I'm wondering if I need to do something with the `item.length === 0` code block now it's wrapped in async function ?

Comment: @paul_cambs: You shouldn't need to, a comparison operation isn't asynchronous.  What specifically isn't working?

Comment: The button doesn't appear when all the images have been processed (unless the page is refershed). I'm not getting any errors in the console though.

Answer (score 2):

Make the event handler function an `async` function and then `await` the calls to the `fetch` and `res.text`

```
item.addEventListener("submit", async function (evt) {
                             /* ^^^^^  make the event handler async */
     ...

     try {
        const response = await fetch("upload-details.php", {
            method: 'post',
            body: formData
        });

        const data = await response.text();
     } catch (error) {
        // handle error
     }

     ...
})
```

Event handler needs to be `async` because that's the function inside which you will use the `await` keyword.

`processImageForms` can be a non-async function because you are not directly using the `await` keyword inside it.

---

**Note:** Instead of adding a separate event listener on each item, I would consider taking advantage of [event bubbling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_bubbling_and_capture) and add a *single* event handler on the common parent element of all items.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out not to be async/await - although it was great to get the answers because they helped my understanding of this paradigm.

It turned out that I needed to re-assign the `uploadMoreImages` variable after `item.remove()` which I did to a new variable `curImageForms`

```
item.remove();

// update imageForms variable
var curImageForms = document.querySelectorAll('.image-upload-details-form')

// show or hide 'upload more images' link on pageload
if (curImageForms.length === 0) {
    uploadMoreImages.style.display = 'inline-block';
}
```

The `uploadMoreImages` was still using the `.length` property assigned prior to the fetch.